# Linked object issue with 2.8RC

Tags: linked-data

I am having an issue with linked objects in 2.8
I have mentioned it on the developer forums but have gotten no response so I thought I would bring it here.
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/error-when-opening-classroom-blend-with-2-8rc/8377
[image]
This started a few weeks ago using the betas and not continues with the RC

In the screenshot I am trying to load the classroom.blend from the examples page on blender.org.
https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/

Any help would be appreciated.  I don't know if this is a bug or how I should be handling duplicated objects.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, both the release candidate and a recent build from the master branch are working fine. Have you modified the scene in anyway? Does this persist with the latest version of Blender?

Comment: No modifications.  just 
OSX 10.14.5
Blender RC
and download and open classroom.blend

Comment: There's been bugs in the first RC release for macOS, try to update it to the most recent one. If that doesn't solve it, it's an issue that should be reported on the bug tracker. https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/

Comment: If you need to send a bug report, I recommend doing it from Blender via Help → Report a Bug, it will pre-fill the ticket with your system and build infos.

Answer (score 0):

I got word from Blender that this is a design decision and no longer supported in blender any longer.

Closed issue.